# Differ between values from different tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have two tables in mysql that contain details about users such as email, first name and last name.

and I made a way to welcome the user that login but the problem is that some value in the two tables are similar which cause duplication,
and I want to know how to differ between values from different tables.

I tried this code but it didn't work:

```
$query=  "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE email = '".$_SESSION['Email']."' NOT IN (SELECT email = '".$_SESSION['Email']."' FROM Table2)";
```

Comment: why are you storing the email in 2 locations?  Store it in 1 table and link that record with a unique id in the second table.  Cuts down on redundant data and keeps consistency when you have update the email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE email = '".$_SESSION['Email']."' NOT IN (SELECT email = '".$_SESSION['Email']."' FROM Table2)
```

The expression `email = '".$_SESSION['Email']."'` is a boolean expression -- essentially `0` or `1`.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE email = '".$_SESSION['Email']."' and
      email NOT IN (SELECT email from Table2 where email = '".$_SESSION['Email']."')
```

Because the comparisons are the same, this is more efficiently written as:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE email = '".$_SESSION['Email']."' and
      not exists (SELECT email from Table2 where email = '".$_SESSION['Email']."')
```

Having an index on `email` in both tables will speed performance.

Answer (score 0):

Have the two tables the same email? Why?

Ok here is maybe a solution if you want only from table 1 the user data from you session email try this:

```
$query = "SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM table t1, table t2 WHERE t1.email <> t2.email AND t1.email = '".$_SESSION["Email"]."'";
```

Recommend: Try to select what you really need... email, username, name etc... not SELECT *

Comment: I am having two tables the same email because its a booking system which mean that users can register from registration page or when they book or make a reservation.